# Speed of application of image changes

Tags: javascript, aviary, camanjs

Not so much an issue as a question... How does Aviary achieve almost instant speed on adjustments e.g. brightness, contrast with sliders or 'effects' (filters e.g. lomo) as they call them?

Can Camanjs match that somehow?

Is it the way it's coded?

I'm about to launch a site using Caman which is a very Social Media centric site but would hate to be seen as a slower version of something. Don't like the Aviary branding but does an end user actually care?

Comment: If you downvote please say why. To me, as a developer I'm very interested how different ways to code somthing can affect this.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't say that I've worked with those, usually when there's a massive speed difference  it is caused by either redundancies in the code, "noob-proofing" or terribad/dirty code.

To answer your other question, unless there is a specific reason for it (large images not loaded asynchronously for some reason, high level of security, multiple database queries, etc.) your website should load relatively fast. IMO, if the site takes more than 2-3 seconds to load, you're doing something wrong.

Hope this helps...

EDIT:

I would suggest using a server-side image manipulator instead aswell as server-side caching techniques to improve the speed of image loading (.i.e. no DB querying)